# Framer Motion exit animation not firing on accordion with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, framer-motion

So I've got this accordion-layout working with `react-router-dom` using a rather unconventional markup structure.

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-violet-kvqn2?file=/src/Case.js

Shortened code for one accordion header:

```
      <motion.div
        layout
        transition={transition}
        key={item.id}
        style={{
          flex: isActive ? 1 : 0,
          flexBasis: isActive ? null : 56,
          ...
        }}
      >
        <NavLink
          style={{
            ...
          }}
          exact={true}
          to={item.url}
        />

        <Route exact path={item.url}>
          <motion.div
            transition={{ delay: 1, ...transition }}
            variants={{
              open: { opacity: 1 },
              collapsed: { opacity: 0 }
            }}
            initial="collapsed"
            animate="open"
            exit="collapsed"
            layout
            style={{
              ...
            }}
          >
            <Home />
          </motion.div>
        </Route>
      </motion.div>
```

And I'm trying to get `framer-motion` to animate between the accordion pages. Like in the gif below

You can see that it works fine to animate the `in` transition. But struggles to animate the `exit` prop on page change. Clicking on an accordion header, the content is abruptly hidden. Looks like it is being removed from the DOM without any consideration to `AnimateSharedLayout` or `AnimatePresence`. I tried adding in `exitBeforeEnter` props but it doesn’t work.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to make some changes in your code:

1. **Work with variants** -> you can [orchestration](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animation/#orchestration) animations start:
   By default, all these animations will start simultaneously. But by using variants, we gain access to extra transition props like when, delayChildren, and staggerChildren that can let parents orchestrate the execution of child animations.
2. Also, looks like you will need to work with `width` to change div sizes. I tried to do with flexBasis but i really couldnt do it, the transition just doesnt work.
3. Remove `<Route>` as a "wrapper" of motion.div. It also stops the motion to do the animations/transitions.
4. Add `<AnimatePresence>` as a wrapper of `motion.div` children. You can check more [here](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/)

So, my code looks like this:

I create this 2 variants:

```
const divVariants = {
  expanded: {
    width: "55%",
   transition: {
      duration: 1.2,
      ease: [0.83, 0, 0.17, 1]
    }
  },
  collapsed: {
    width: "15%",
    transition: {
      duration: 1.2,
      ease: [0.83, 0, 0.17, 1]
    }
  }
};

const tagVariants = {
  show: {
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      delay: 1,
      duration: 1.2,
      ease: [0.83, 0, 0.17, 1]
    }
  },
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    transition: {
      duration: 1.2,
      ease: [0.83, 0, 0.17, 1]
    }
  }
};
```

motion.div :

```html
<!-- Parent -->
<motion.div
        layout
        variants={divVariants}
        animate={isActive ? "expanded" : "collapsed"}
        initial={false}
        data-section={item.id}
        key={item.id}
        style={{
          overflow: "hidden",
          zIndex: i,
          display: "flex",
          position: "relative",
          backgroundColor: `hsl(${i * 20},100%,50%)`
        }}
      >

<!-- Children -->
<AnimatePresence>
          {isActive && (
            <motion.div
              layout
              variants={tagVariants}
              initial="hidden"
              animate="show"
              exit="hidden"
              style={{
                padding: 20,
                maxWidth: "100%",
                maxHeight: "100%",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                overflowY: "hidden",
                overflowX: "hidden"
              }}
            >
              <Tag data={data} />
            </motion.div>
          )}
        </AnimatePresence>
```

I also added some inline styles to all Cases:

```html
<div
      <!-- Avoid div to wrap when it is collapsing -->
      style={{
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
        overflow: "hidden"
      }}
    >
      home 0
    </div>
```

### And finally

***You can check the code [here!](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-pine-lg9vo)***

Comment: Hi Luis, that works really well! Thank you so much. Small question is there anything I can do about the panes collapsing too much if I click through too fast? I recorded a gif here explaining what I mean: https://giphy.com/gifs/SwrY9WAadYfnxYLD0u

Comment: Hey umbriel, a simple workround is set to your nav background the same background color of the last div, in this case '#ffff00'. I' ve saved my codesandbox with the change.

Comment: Yeah thats a clever workaround. I'll accept the answer now & bounty reward once the 5 days expires. Thanks again